# OpenCV Video capture from file won't open successfully

Tags: c++, opencv

I've written this in C++ (VS2012) using the OpenCV library (2.4.6).

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>    
int main(){
    Mat image;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open("test.avi");
    if(!cap.isOpened()){
        cout<< "Capture not open \n";
        cin.get();
    }
    cvNamedWindow("Video Output");
    while(1){
        cap >> image;
        imshow("Video Output",image);
        waitKey(30);
    }
}
```

Running it, the video capture fails to open.
test.avi is located in the same directory as the executable, and running it ind Debug/Release/outside the IDE makes no difference.
The OpenCv DLLs and the video file are here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/16c04d97iw90gtk/88fQ4BLbfl#/
What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT: As seen in questions on the OpenCV Q&A site, I've copied the opencv_ffmpeg DLL to the folder with my executable. Now it only works outside the IDE (VS2012)

Comment: have you tried other video files? Maybe it is some problem with the file.

Comment: "fails to open" what do mean by that ? is it giving any error message please describe.

Comment: As Mailerdaimon suggested try another video file. I recently tried some video code and had to search a while until I found a free video online that worked.
Try `StopMoti2001.mpeg` from https://archive.org/details/StopMoti2001
https://archive.org/download/StopMoti2001/StopMoti2001.mpeg

Comment: I've tried other avi and .mov files, I'll try this one now.

Comment: What I mean by fails to open is that cap.isOpened() returns false and then imshow() raises an exception because the image returned in the previous line has a resolution of 0x0

Answer (score 9):

You should copy the opencv_ffmpeg DLL in your targetDir, in this case the Debug executable folder, other than the Release one